# JSoup - Formatting the <option> elements

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

Let's say I have this HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <select name="books"> 
                <option value="111">111</option>
                <option value="222">222</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I load it in Jsoup and get the result back :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(4);
doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(true);
String result = doc.outerHtml();
```

This result is :

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method="post"> 
            <select name="books"> <option value="111">111</option> <option value="222">222</option> </select> 
        </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The `<option>` elements are all on the same line!

How can I have Jsoup to format the `<option>` elements so the result is the same than the input, in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
```

When parsing just html from a string, the default charset is UTF-8, unless you otherwise set the charset using `File` or `InputStream` as your parse input.

Therefore, the charset on `OutputSettings` will default to the same as input, which is UTF-8, in your case.  You only need to set this if you want it to be different from the input.

[`Document.OutputSettings.charset()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#charset--)

> Get the document's current output charset, which is used to control which characters are escaped when generating HTML (via the html() methods), and which are kept intact.
>
> Where possible (when parsing from a URL or File), the document's output charset is automatically set to the input charset. Otherwise, it defaults to UTF-8.

---

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(true);
```

You don't need to enable pretty print, it is on by default.

[`Document.OutputSettings.prettyPrint()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint--)

> Get if pretty printing is enabled. Default is true. If disabled, the
>   HTML output methods will not re-format the output, and the output will
>   generally look like the input.

---

```
doc.outputSettings().outline(true);
```

This is the key tag.  When this is not set, only block tags are displayed as such (`option` is [not a block tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)).  When it is enabled, all tags are considered block elements.

[`Document.OutputSettings.outline()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#outline--)

> Get if outline mode is enabled. Default is false. If enabled, the HTML output methods will consider all tags as block.

---

So your final block of code should look something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(4).outline(true);

String result = doc.outerHtml();
```

**Output**

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method="post"> 
            <select name="books"> 
                <option value="111">111</option> 
                <option value="222">222</option> 
            </select> 
        </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```